# Can someone identify this flowering bush from the US?

Tags: botany, species-identification

This bush is in Tennessee, USA.:
[image: flower bush pic 1]
[image: flower bush pic 2]
[image: flower bush pic 3:]
[image: flower bush pic 4:]

Comment: @DevashishDas , red horse chestnut is a tree...the Q. refers it as a bush...

Comment: Maybe the tree was young so looking like bush. young trees sometimes can flower.

Comment: Not sure about the ID, but those are definitely flowers, not fruits. You can see some of the fallen blossoms on the leaves in one of the photos.

Comment: Red flowering Japanese knotweed.

Answer (score 4):

Polygonum cuspidatum, common name Japanese knotweed. A notorious invasive species.

It's actually a herbaceous perennial (those stems grew in just one season, and will die back to the ground at the first hard freeze), not a shrub. The red things are ripening seeds, not flowers.

Comment: Can you please add some reference to support your answer?

Comment: *Polygonum cuspidatum*? Google shows white flower for them.

Comment: *It is quite showy as it booms in cascades of silver flowers in late August **that turn an intense magenta and then to scarlet** each year right at time of the solstice.* --[Bitter Orange and Japanese Knotweed](https://thepoppainter.wordpress.com/2008/09/26/bitter-orange-and-japanese-knotweed-autumn-has-arrived/)